# python class visibility inside nested class

Tags: python, class, nested

If I have a code like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class MainClass:
    class Options(Enum):
        OPTION1=1
        OPTION2=2
        OPTION3=3
    class InternalOperation:
        def function1(self, o):
            if o == Options.OPTION1:
                x=0
                ......
       function1= staticmethod(function1)
```

I am having trouble doing it and do not know if is it possible to make the enum class visible to the second class inside the main class and how.

Comment: You don't need a `MainClass`. Is there a reason you're using one?

Comment: What trouble are you having? Because `Options` should be visible inside `InternalOperation` declaration as is.

Comment: @dhke except it seems like it isn't

Comment: I am getting a message like this : AttributeError: type object 'ComponentFactory' has no attribute 'ComponentSize'

Comment: If you take everything out of the `MainClass` class, it works. If there's no particular reason you need it, I'd simply remove it.

Comment: *This* code won't raise *that* error…

Comment: `function1` is no static method. If so use `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: ah, dammit, the inner class doesn't inherit the namespace of the outer class ...

Comment: @daniel there are already doing that

Comment: ah, using static function was giving me funky message got foced to put the class as parameter because of self in the function, I am removing it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the outer class `MainClass.Options.OPTION1`:

```
from enum import Enum

class MainClass:
    class Options(Enum):
        OPTION1=1
        OPTION2=2
        OPTION3=3
    class InternalOperation:
        def function1(self, o):
            if o == MainClass.Options.OPTION1:
                x= 0
```

Don't make it a static method if you use `self` as the first argument.